# When deploying GCP cloud function with go client I receive: "Error 400: Precondition check failed., failedPrecondition"

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a Google Cloud Function using the go client package by google.

(https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/cloudfunctions/v1?tab=doc#pkg-overview)

I have broken it down into the snippet I think is most relevant:

```
import (
    "context"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    functions "google.golang.org/api/cloudfunctions/v1"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    CloudFunctionService, err := functions.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error at functions.NewService(ctx): \"%v\"\n", err)
    }
    FunctionSpec := functions.CloudFunction{
            EntryPoint:        "DeployThisFunctionEntryPoint",
            EventTrigger: &functions.EventTrigger{
                EventType: "google.pubsub.topic.publish",
                Resource:  "projects/mytestproject/topics/cloud-builds",
            },
            Name:                "DeployThisFunction",
            Runtime:             "go111",
            SourceRepository:    &functions.SourceRepository{Url: "https://source.developers.google.com/projects/mytestproject/repos/deploythisfunction/moveable-aliases/master/paths//"},
    }
    CloudFunctionDeploymentService := functions.NewProjectsLocationsFunctionsService(CloudFunctionService)
    createCall := CloudFunctionDeploymentService.Create("projects/mytestproject/locations/us-central1", &FunctionSpec)
    resp, err := createCall.Context(ctx).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error at createCall.Context(ctx).Do(): \"%v\"\n", err)
    }
    log.Printf("response createCall.Context(ctx).Do(): \"%v\"\n", resp)
}
```

However, no matter how I format it or try. I always get the following message:

```
googleapi: Error 400: Precondition check failed., failedPrecondition
```

Through the google api explorer I ran the request with their authentication and json scheme and I received the same error.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/create

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Precondition check failed.",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out what is going wrong. I have started my own project and am the administrator. When running another part of the go client with GCP for instance creating storage, IAM user, serviceaccounts, database I can make it work and create these resources.

If anyone has encountered this problem I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [eventType](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#SourceRepository) should match pattern : `providers/*/eventTypes/*.*.`  .

For exmple:`providers/cloud.pubsub/eventTypes/topic.publish`

Also SourceRepository url should be `https://source.developers.google.com/projects/*/repos/*/revisions/*/paths/`
and you have `https://source.developers.google.com/projects/mytestproject/repos/deploythisfunction/moveable-aliases/master/paths//`

The error message says that is an issue with the way you configure `FunctionSpec`, I suspect `EventTrigger` or `SourceRepository` fields.

## Edit

The `code: 400` is a bad request, client error, in this case formatting issue, and the first thing to check is each [cloud function fileds](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#SourceRepository)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I actually took a lot of these values from a successful deploy log message in the console.
```
"request": {
"location": "projects/mytestproject/locations/us-central1",
"function": {
"entryPoint": "DeployThisFu...",
"eventTrigger": {
"eventType": "google.pubsub.topic.publish",
"resource": "projects/mytestproject/topics/cloud-builds"},
"sourceRepository": {
"url":"https://source.developers.google.com/projects/mytestproject/repos/deploythisfunction/moveable-aliases/master/paths//"}}},
```

I agree though I think there's issue with the functionSpec thanks